# Resolve an instance of type 'B' for each instance of type 'A'

Tags: ioc-container, autofac

I have an interface called specification:

```
public interface ISpecification { ... }
```

Many implementations of this can exist within my application and I also have a processor which requires a specification:

```
public interface IProcessor { ... }

public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    public Processor (ISpecification specification) { ... }
}
```

I am using Autofac (version 3.5.2) as my IOC container, what I would like is to be able to call:

```
var processors = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IProcessor>>();
```

And have one `IProcessor` returned for each registered `ISpecification`, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like Autofac's [Adapters](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Adapters-And-Decorators):

> Autofac provides built-in adapter registration so you can register a
>   set of services and have them each automatically adapted to a
>   different interface.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the services to be adapted
builder.RegisterType<SaveCommand>()
       .As<ICommand>()
       .WithMetadata("Name", "Save File");
builder.RegisterType<OpenCommand>()
       .As<ICommand>()
       .WithMetadata("Name", "Open File");

// Then register the adapter. In this case, the ICommand
// registrations are using some metadata, so we're
// adapting Meta<ICommand> instead of plain ICommand.
builder.RegisterAdapter<Meta<ICommand>, ToolbarButton>(
   cmd =>
    new ToolbarButton(cmd.Value, (string)cmd.Metadata["Name"]));

var container = builder.Build();

// The resolved set of buttons will have two buttons
// in it - one button adapted for each of the registered
// ICommand instances.
var buttons = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ToolbarButton>>();
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, I'll check it out!